# How do I make an object increase a certain speed every few points in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to increase the speed of a ball after 5 points until a certain speed is reached. How can I do it efficiently?

let's say

```
       local speed=0
       local score=0
       local ball
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. `Speed` is calculate acording to `score`

```
local mFloor = math.floor
local mMin = math.min

local pointStep = 5
local speedStep = 0.2
local startSpeed = 0
local speedLimit = 4
local times = mFloor( score / pointStep )

speed = times * speedStep + startSpeed
speed = mMin( speed, speedLimit )
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem then maybe this little piece of code will help you :)

```
 if(score%5==0)then

 speed=speed+0.2   

 end
```